# Creating a session manager to know timeout swift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a token response with expiry time and I want to be able to present a view once the expiry time is reached. The expiry passed as a date String from the server but I am currently converting it to int with the purpose of using timeInterval to compare it with current time and if it equal to or less than the current time, the view should be presented.

I planned on using an Observables to listen on login so I pass the time int into a `BehaviorRelay` then I have a `BaseviewController` which all view controllers inherit from. Once I do this, I subscribe to the `Behavior`.

I created a SessionMonitor Protocol

```
protocol SessionMonitor {
    var isTokenExpired: BehaviorRelay<Int?> { get }
}
```

I then extended my LoginPresenter

```
    class LoginPresenter: LoginProtocol.Presenter, SessionMonitor {
        var isTokenExpired = BehaviorRelay<Int?>(value: 0)

         ....

 // In my login function

     func login(....) {
       //http response
       guard let interval = resp.tokens?.first?.getExpires()?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.int else { return
                }
                self.isTokenExpired.accept(interval)
       }
    }
```

so in my Parent view controller I have this

```
private var presenter: SessionMonitor?
```

in the viewDidload

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        isTokenExpired.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance).subscribe(onNext: { time in
            log(time, .happy)
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
}
```

But I do not get anything in my log on Login successful despite seeing that the expiry time is present in my response.

Also I just decided to try this approach to solve my problem and if anyone with a better way to go about this, I would be glad.

More code would be supplied on request.

Comment: The tough part of this problem is really the fact that the token can expire while the app is in the background. How were you planning on handling that? What is the expected behavior fo the app in that case?

Comment: so if the app moves to the background, the splash screen is called where a check is made but I could as well just check the expiry time which is saved locally and checkit against current time. if <= current time then timeout.